# Fourier transform of I (modified, first kind) Bessel function

Tags: integration, fourier-transform, distribution-theory, bessel-functions

It is known that
$$\int_{-1}^1 (1-x^2)^\lambda e^{ixs}dx = \sqrt{\pi}\Gamma(\lambda+1)\left(\frac{s}{2} \right)^{-\lambda-\frac{1}{2}}J_{\lambda+\frac{1}{2}}(s). \qquad (1)$$
One also has
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty (1+x^2)^\lambda e^{ixs}dx = \frac{2\sqrt{\pi}}{\Gamma(-\lambda)}\left|\frac{s}{2} \right|^{-\lambda-\frac{1}{2}}K_{-\lambda-\frac{1}{2}}(|s|). \qquad (2)$$
This can be found, for example, in the 1st volume of Gel'fand and Shilov on distributions.

I am wondering what is the inverse Fourier transform of
$$\sqrt{\pi}\Gamma(\lambda+1)\left(\frac{s}{2} \right)^{-\lambda-\frac{1}{2}}I_{\lambda+\frac{1}{2}}(s)? \qquad (3)$$
Clearly, it is related to the right hand side of (1) by $s\to is$. So, one can just try to make a substitution $s\to is$, $x\to -ix$, but then one is lead to integrate over $x$ from $-i$ to $+i$. I do not see how this contour can be replaced with the real one, so I do not understand how to get the Fourier transform along these lines.

Of course, I understand that $I$ is exponentially growing, so this integral does not converge in the normal sense. Still, I guess, Fourier transforms can be defined for a large class of functions in the sense of distributions (e.g. in Gel'fand Shilov one evaluates Fourier transforms of exp[ax] with real a).

Any ideas?

Comment: Mathematica indicates $f_{\lambda}(s)=\sqrt{\pi}\,\Gamma(\lambda+1)\,\left(\frac{s}{2}\right)^{-\lambda -\frac{1}{2}} I_{\lambda+\frac{1}{2}}(s)$ simplifies to $f_{\lambda}(s)=\sqrt{\pi}\,\Gamma(\lambda +1)\,_0\tilde{F}_1\left(;\lambda+\frac{3}{2};\frac{s^2}{4}\right)$ and $\mathcal{F}_s^{-1}[f_{\lambda}(s)](x)=0$.

Comment: Thank you, Steven. This looks curious. Though, clearly, 0 is not a correct answer (at least for the Fourier transform is invertible). I tend to think that one cannot do better than an integral in the complex plane as I suggested in the original post. Similar thing happens for exp[ax] with real a: its Fourier transform is a simple pole at ia and the associated distribution involves a contour integral around this pole, not along the real line. Apparently, there are setups in which integrals in the complex plane are unavoidable

Comment: I suspect you're right that the inverse Fourier transform actually evaluates to a distribution (or set of distributions?) that is zero almost everywhere, and Mathematica's evaluation of the inverse Fourier transform is incorrect.

Comment: The exact meaning of the FT of $e^{ax}$ would be welcome (in place of "I guess" ;)

Comment: @metamorphy $F[e^{bx}]=2\pi \delta (s-ib)$. The delta function is defined as a functional $(\delta(s-s_0),\psi)=\psi(s_0)$, where $s_0$ can be any complex number. It can alternatively be defined as a contour integral in the complex plane using that $\psi(s_0)=(2\pi i)^{-1}\int_\Gamma \psi(s)ds/(s-s_0))$, where $\Gamma$ encircles $s_0$. Such functionals are called analytic in Gel'fand-Shilov. In other words it is hard to associated this functional with a real function as integration contour is in the complex plane